# How does Azure Active Directory support federation with Okta as an IDP?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, okta, ws-federation, federation

Is it possible to integrate [Okta](https://www.okta.com/) as an IDP (Identity Provider) for an application in Azure, where Azure would be the Service Provider?

Presently the authentication is managed by Azure AD, we have AD users that have been granted access to these applications hosted in Azure, and Use [ADAL](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js) for logging in users, and obtaining tokens for securing API calls to the Backend APIs.

Can Okta be added as an IDP and added to the AAD, through SAML or WS-Federation?

Comment: Did you [see this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ee6bfd3f-3c4a-4201-9800-8189e67b4dea/how-can-we-integrate-okta-as-idp-in-azure-ad?forum=WindowsAzureAD)?

Comment: Or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34297152/azure-ad-as-federation-provider-for-okta)?  Kinda old now though...

Comment: This one looks promising: [Okta AD Integration with Azure AD Domain Services](https://alanschmarr.wordpress.com/2016/02/22/okta-ad-integration-with-azure-ad-domain-services/)

Comment: Thanks @spottedmahn, I've skimmed through these whilst looking for a solution, the B2C Custom option looks promising, as that might provide a seamless under the hood integration without writing custom code or authentication in the Web App.

Comment: any luck, figuring this out? I've been searching for a while and haven't got a clear answer yet either.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, **OKTA** is listed as one of the third-party IDPs in the [Azure AD federation compatibility list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/connect/active-directory-aadconnect-federation-compatibility) which can support federation with Azure Active Directory (AAD).

The supported scenario matrix is listed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/connect/active-directory-aadconnect-federation-compatibility#okta).

Hope this clarifies your doubt.

Comment: Yes, I have looked at the documentation already, but it doesn't clarify how to have it to federated with the AAD. I have managed to create a standalone authentication work without the AAD by using Okta as an IDP through WS-Federation.